# ¿Cómo podemos llamar al "drafting" del triatlón en español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, deportes

En el mundo de los triatlones hay siempre mucha controversia con un concepto: el 'drafting'. Consiste en que en la parte de ciclismo te pones detrás de otro ciclista y sigues su ritmo. De este modo consigues que él se *coma* el viento y tú puedas ir a su misma velocidad, pero con menor esfuerzo.

Tan importante es el tema, que las competiciones se dividen en dos: las que permiten el 'drafting' y las que no.

Recientemente descubrí que también se utiliza este término en el atletismo, a raíz de [una pregunta que hice en Physical Fitness Stack Exchange](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/39604/23370): lo mismo, se utiliza para explicar el efecto de estar corriendo detrás de una persona y aprovechar su esfuerzo para no sentir tanto viento y, más psicológicamente, para no tener que pensar en un ritmo y centrarse en ir al del otro.

Mirando en webs de triatlón en castellano veo que siempre se utiliza el concepto en inglés. Por ejemplo en [¿Qué es el drafting?](https://elultimotriatleta.com/que-es-drafting/) dicen:

> Un grupo de ciclistas circulará en una línea cerrada, uno detrás del otro, tomando turnos para adelantarse antes de despegarse y engancharse en la parte posterior.  Cuando se circulas de esta manera, pegando tu rueda delantera a la trasera del otro ciclista, gastas menos energía, se calcula un 30% menos de resistencia al viento.
>
> Beneficios del drafting
>
> Vale, vale, vale, puedes pensar que ir en pelotón será muy sencillo ya que pedalearás con menor esfuerzo. Si bien esto es cierto en ciertas circunstancias, irás muy cómodo, con poca resistencia y será un paseo fácil, pero también en ocasiones tendrás que apretar mucho más fuerte cuando el grupo está girando a toda velocidad. Tendrás más períodos de tiempo en los que estés pedaleando suave o sin viento, pero luego seguirás pedaleando más fuerte de lo que lo harías.

Entonces la pregunta sería: ¿cómo podríamos nombrar este concepto en castellano?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [**rebufo**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=VLo5LqX)
> ...
> 2. m. Vacío que deja un móvil y que puede aprovechar el que sigue.

Ya se aplica este término al mismo fenómeno en otros deportes de vehículos [motorizados]:

> #### [Competición deportiva](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebufo)
>
> El rebufo es una técnica de adelantamiento de un vehículo motorizado (ya sea monoplaza, motocicleta, coche de carreras, etc) a otro vehículo. Es utilizada por los pilotos de carreras, muy vista en automovilismo. Se genera cuando uno o varios pilotos con sus vehículos se ponen detrás de otros y consiguen entrar en un *túnel de succión aerodinámico* que genera el que tiene delante, consiguiendo así una mayor velocidad punta al final de recta gracias a la poca resistencia que el aire genera en dicho túnel. Así con menor potencia consiguen la misma velocidad que el vehículo que les antecede y les queda potencia para acelerar cuando salen de la estela del vehículo y así poder adelantarlo antes de la frenada o tras llegar a una curva o una chicana.